# Custom UpdateView in Python

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to get a custom UpdateView to work in Python/Django.  I believe that the code that I've writtten is mostly correct, as it seems to be returning the proper Primary Key ID in the URL when I click on the associated dropdown.  The problem is that I am not seeing any of the data associated with this record on the screen in update mode.  The screen appears in edit mode, but there is no data.  I suspect the problem is perhaps the django template in the html form?  However, I have played with the form and used {{ form }} and it too returns a blank form.  I've played with this all afternoon and I'm out of guesses.  Here is my view:

```
def updating_document(request, pk):
    doc = get_object_or_404(Doc, pk=pk)
    form = Update_Doc_Form(request.user, request.POST)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('App:main_procedure_menu'))
    else:
        print("Form is invalid!")
    return render(request,'Doc/update_doc.html',{'form':form })
```

I also have an associated form...

Form.py

```
   class Update_Doc_Form(forms.ModelForm):       

     class Meta:
        model = Doc 
        exclude = ['user']

        doc_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput)
        description = forms.CharField(required=True,widget=forms.Textarea)
        team = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select)
        document = forms.CharField(required=True,widget=forms.Textarea)

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(Update_Doc_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['doc_name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'name'
            self.fields['description'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'description'
            self.fields['team'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'choices'
            self.fields['team'].empty_label = ''
```

I'm a newbie, but I do want to use a custom UpdateView so that I can alter some of the fields and pass user information.  I feel like the code is close, just need to figure out why it's not actually populating the form with data.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a difference a day makes.  Found an answer on SO this morning.  Not sure how to credit the person or issue number....

The answer was to add the following line of code to my form:

```
    user = kwargs.pop('object_user')
```

I also needed to add the following function to my View:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(ViewName,self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({'object_user':self.request.user})
    return kwargs
```

This question was answered originally in 2013 by Ivan ViraByan.  Thanks Ivan!

I ultimately went with a standard class based UpdateView and scrapped my plans for the custom UpdateView once I was able to figure out how to use the Class Based View(UpdateView) and "pop" off the user information when passing it to the form based on Ivan ViraByan's answer in 2013.

The code above allows you to get the user but not pass it to the ModelForm so that you don't get the unexpected user error.